# Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Cuando intento actualizar Eclipse Luna 4.11.0, surge el siguiente error.
¿Como puedo solucianorlo?

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

Software being installed: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.18.100.v20190916-1045 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.18.100.v20190916-1045)

Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers 4.11.0.20190314-1200 (epp.package.jee 4.11.0.20190314-1200)

Only one of the following can be installed at once:

```
Debug Core 3.14.0.v20190812-1404 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.14.0.v20190812-1404)
Debug Core 3.11.0.v20170605-1534 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.11.0.v20170605-1534)
Debug Core 3.13.200.v20190216-1557 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.13.200.v20190216-1557)
```

Cannot satisfy dependency:

```
From: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers 4.11.0.20190314-1200 (epp.package.jee 4.11.0.20190314-1200)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.11.0.v20190307-0500,4.11.0.v20190307-0500]
```

Cannot satisfy dependency:

```
From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.18.100.v20190916-1045 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.18.100.v20190916-1045)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.jdt.launching [3.15.0.v20190826-1639,3.15.0.v20190826-1639]
```

Cannot satisfy dependency:

```
From: Java Development Tools Launching Support 3.15.0.v20190826-1639 (org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.15.0.v20190826-1639)
To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.debug.core [3.14.0,4.0.0)
```

Cannot satisfy dependency:

```
From: Eclipse Platform 4.11.0.v20190307-0500 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.11.0.v20190307-0500)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.debug.core [3.13.200.v20190216-1557,3.13.200.v20190216-1557]
```

Comment: Ese manejo de dependencias nunca me gustó en eclipse, y eso que yo no lo uso desde Ganymede. Instala la nueva versión desde cero y conservas las preferencias

Comment: Lo intentare, gracias.

Comment: Eso resolvio el problema, muchas gracias.